# Get case comments with comment author information and author type on Servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want to fetch the comments with comments author information like author name, email, type (Requester or Assignee) etc from servicenow api.

for that I used this REST API

https://service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_journal_field?sysparm_query=element_id=ddb834dd47d6a110...

so this API gives responce like

```
"result": [     
     {
        "sys_id": "55f375ed479ae110c2fd8977536d4345",
        "sys_created_on": "2023-04-19 01:44:09",
        "name": "sn_customerservice_case",
        "element_id": "ddb834dd47d6a110c2fd8977536d438d",
        "sys_tags": "",
        "value": "Issue is not resolved",
        "sys_created_by": "akshay",
        "element": "comments"
     }
```

]

But I am expecting some more information about comment author like username , email, type of author is requester or assignee etc in the responce. so is there any API in servicenow which help me to get the responce.

Comment: You could make another request to the `user` table, might you only have the userID to use to find the user in that case. For your requirements though, it sounds like you're better off creating a scripted REST API call